# How to test that a Panic is thrown in Golang?

Tags: testing, go

I am able to force the throw of a Panic statement, but no matter what I try I am unable to test it.

**Test**

```
func TestPanicStatement(t *testing.T) {
    expected := "error"
    actual := function("/file/does/not/exist.xml")
    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("Test failed, expected: '%s', got:  '%s'", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

**Outcome**

```
--- FAIL: TestPanicStatement (0.00s)
panic: EOF [recovered]
    panic: EOF

goroutine 8 [running]:
```